# Jquery not working on Angular 2 APP

Tags: jquery, html, angular

```html
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRoute} from "@angular/router";
@Component({
  selector: 'tutorial',
  template: `    
  <div class="page container">     
     
  </div>
`
})
export class TutorialComponent {

  constructor( public route:ActivatedRoute){

  }


  ngOnInit() {
    $.get('http://localhost:8001/tutorials/tutorials_homepage.html', function(data){
      $('body > app-root > span > div > tutorial > div').append($(data)).filter('.container');
      $('HEAD').append($(data)).filter('SCRIPT');

    });



  }

}
```

I created a angular 2 app which imports a html file from another server. HTML works properly fine when directly accessed but when it is imported to angular 2, code does nothing.
Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#hide").click(function(){
        $("p").hide();
    });
    $("#show").click(function(){
        $("p").show();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>If you click on the "Hide" button, I will disappear.</p>

<button id="hide">Hide</button>
<button id="show">Show</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Can somebody help me!!!

Comment: Nope we cant because we dont have your angular code !!

Comment: On the angular side I just import this file

Comment: How do you import this file is exactly what could be causing the problem. Because the code you posted is working fine. We cant help you without the broken code

Comment: @Component({
  selector: 'tutorial',
  template: `    
  <div class="page container">     
     
  </div>
`
})

 
  ngOnInit() {
    $.get(fileName, function(data){
      $('body > app-root > span > div > tutorial > div').append($(data)).filter('.container');
      $('HEAD').append($(data)).filter('SCRIPT');

    });

Comment: above is my code for the angular part

Comment: can you add it to your question ???. It's not readable inside comments

Comment: I have posted angular side as well and html file as well

Comment: You did not import jquery

Comment: So.... your HTML file doesn't mention Angular at all.

Comment: In angular file I am importing that file, and appending the content of html file to container clas

Comment: This approach confuses me... Why not just create a `tutorials-homepage.component`, then use it in your html? Alternatively, does the html really need to be added to the DOM if not, just use an `<iframe>`?